# Bind JSON Data in JQGrid with find and search option using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid

When i bind Json data in JQgrid in my asp.net application i cant able to see the Fin icon button. I have set the search:true in the js file,but thats not working

Comment: I kniw it's a bit late, but I you came back here, please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) method to have navigator bar with the "Search" button.